# inline math with \ldots

Tags: math-mode, inline

what should be preferred: `$x_1,\, x_2,\ldots,\, x_n$` or `$x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$`
I'm hesitating for the `\ldots` versus `...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$x_1$,~$x_2$, \dots,~$x_n$
```

is OK.

[image]

This is how Knuth use in TeXbook.

For me, I would replace the tildes with spaces.

I don't think one should use `...` instead of `\dots` or `\ldots`.

Comment: it looks like in a normal sentence, `...` should be used instead of `\dots` (at least in French as far as I know). When maths are involved, I am not sure

Comment: I know nothing about French typography. In modern fonts, there is a `…` symbol and I think it should be used. (It is used when you use `xunicode` with XeLaTeX.) At least in TeX, `\dots,` and `\dots.` are widely used.